# Running HIve query through impala.dbapi fails when embedding "Add Jar"

Tags: python, hive

I'm launching a hive query through python `impala.dbapi`, which works nicely as following:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from impala.dbapi import connect
from impala.util import as_pandas
from datetime import datetime

user=os.environ['HIVE_USER']
password=os.environ['HIVE_PASSWORD']
up_to_date_query = '''  
select * from dejavu.tracking_events limit 1
 ''' 
conn = connect(host='ecprdbhdp02-clientgw.kenshooprd.local', port=10000,
                   user=user,
                   password=password,
                   auth_mechanism='PLAIN')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(up_to_date_query)
df = as_pandas(cursor)
df.head()
```

But when i'm adding the following "`Add Jar`" clause as following:

```
up_to_date_query = '''  
 ADD JAR hdfs://BICluster/user/yossis/udfs/hive-udf-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;
 select * from dejavu.tracking_events limit 1
 '''
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HiveServer2Error                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-1e512abcc69e> in <module>()
      4                    auth_mechanism='PLAIN')
      5 cursor = conn.cursor()
----> 6 cursor.execute(up_to_date_query)
      7 df = as_pandas(cursor)
      8 df.head()

/home/yehoshaphats/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.pyc in execute(self, operation, parameters, configuration)
    300         # PEP 249
    301         self.execute_async(operation, parameters=parameters,
--> 302                            configuration=configuration)
    303         log.debug('Waiting for query to finish')
    304         self._wait_to_finish()  # make execute synchronous

/home/yehoshaphats/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.pyc in execute_async(self, operation, parameters, configuration)
    341             self._last_operation = op
    342 
--> 343         self._execute_async(op)
    344 
    345     def _debug_log_state(self):

/home/yehoshaphats/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.pyc in _execute_async(self, operation_fn)
    360         self._reset_state()
    361         self._debug_log_state()
--> 362         operation_fn()
    363         self._last_operation_active = True
    364         self._debug_log_state()

/home/yehoshaphats/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.pyc in op()
    338             op = self.session.execute(self._last_operation_string,
    339                                       configuration,
--> 340                                       async=True)
    341             self._last_operation = op
    342 

/home/yehoshaphats/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.pyc in execute(self, statement, configuration, async)
   1025                                    confOverlay=configuration,
   1026                                    runAsync=async)
-> 1027         return self._operation('ExecuteStatement', req)
   1028 
   1029     def get_databases(self, schema='.*'):

/home/yehoshaphats/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.pyc in _operation(self, kind, request)
    955 
    956     def _operation(self, kind, request):
--> 957         resp = self._rpc(kind, request)
    958         return self._get_operation(resp.operationHandle)
    959 

/home/yehoshaphats/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.pyc in _rpc(self, func_name, request)
    923         response = self._execute(func_name, request)
    924         self._log_response(func_name, response)
--> 925         err_if_rpc_not_ok(response)
    926         return response
    927 

/home/yehoshaphats/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.pyc in err_if_rpc_not_ok(resp)
    702             resp.status.statusCode != TStatusCode.SUCCESS_WITH_INFO_STATUS and
    703             resp.status.statusCode != TStatusCode.STILL_EXECUTING_STATUS):
--> 704         raise HiveServer2Error(resp.status.errorMessage)
    705 
    706 

HiveServer2Error: Error while processing statement: null
```

Notice that the query works properly when running it directly in Hive (through the `hue` console).

After searching for similar questions, it seems like no one asked for exactly the same problem :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the `;` separator causes trouble, I've just separated it as following:

```
cursor.execute('ADD JAR hdfs://BICluster/user/yossis/udfs/hive-udf-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')

up_to_date_query = '''  
  select * from dejavu.tracking_events limit 1
 ''' 
cursor.execute(up_to_date_query)
```